# Change Hamburger Menu Icon in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

How can I change the hamburger menu icon in a .NET MAUI app?

I've updated the style of all my icons and I want to change the hamburger menu icon to a custom `PNG`.

I tried the following in `Styles.xaml` but that doesn't seem to be the correct property to edit.

```
<Style TargetType="FlyoutPage">
    <Setter Property="IconImageSource" Value="custom_menu_icon.png" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I am trying to create a hamburger menu without a success. Can you show me your code for example, please.

Comment: Are you using `AppShell` in your MAUI app? If so, do you have `FlyoutItem`'s defined in `AppShell.xaml`?

Comment: Yes I am using AppShell. I tried everything and never got any result (visible result).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for FlyoutPage**

The Flyout of the `FlyoutPage` is of type `ContentPage` and thus the icon should be set there instead:

```xml
<ContentPage
    IconImageSource="custom_menu_icon.png" />
</ContentPage>
```

You can also define it in the `Styles.xaml` and assign the style to the page:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ContentPage" x:Key="FlyoutStyle">
    <Setter Property="IconImageSource" Value="custom_menu_icon.png" />
</Style>
```

```xml
<ContentPage
    Style="{StaticResource FlyoutStyle}" />
</ContentPage>
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/flyoutpage?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-flyoutpage

This assumes that you're using the `FlyoutPage` and not `Shell`.

**Solution for Shell**

In case you're using Shell, you can define the style as follows:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <!-- skipping existing setters here -->
    <Setter Property="Shell.FlyoutIcon" Value="custom_menu_icon.png" />
</Style>
```

See more: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-7.0#flyout-icon

Answer (score 1):

In your shell page, you can do add a propety:

```
<Shell FlyoutIcon="yourimage.png" ...
```

I hope this helps :)

[image]