# How do you change the color of the burger bar in maui when using shell

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

Looked everywhere but could not find it

How do you change the color of the burger bar in maui when using shell

Thanks

Comment: Please show what exactly you want to achieve and show your code (as text) when asking questions.

Comment: Show me your burgers. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the burger icon in a MAUI Shell Flyout, you can set the `ForegroundColor`:

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="MAUIApp1.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MAUIApp1"
    FlyoutBackgroundColor="Black"
    Shell.ForegroundColor="Orange">

</Shell>
```

Maybe this helps, too: [Change Hamburger Menu Icon in .NET MAUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424845/change-hamburger-menu-icon-in-net-maui-app)

Or this: [How to get the default shell flyout icon to react when android dark theme is switched on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74252720/how-to-get-the-default-shell-flyout-icon-to-react-when-android-dark-theme-is-swi)

Comment: the link you posted really helps. Basically if in darkMode I am changing the statusbar to be the same color as the background of the page to give a more fluid look if you like and I wanted to change the burger bar icon color accordingly.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74252720/how-to-get-the-default-shell-flyout-icon-to-react-when-android-dark-theme-is-swi/74253764#74253764

Comment: that works! one last bit , is it possible to independenlty change the color of battery etc. basically the text that is inside the status bar - indipendently from the the statusbar backgroundcolor?

Comment: That's a different question. AFAIK you cannot change the color of the status bar text to anything that you like, instead you can (on Android at least), only change it's appearance to light or dark. But again, separate question (and please do some research here before, this type of question usually comes up often)

Comment: I have done my research I could not find an answer but thank you for resolving my issue . I am new to shell as I always used prism...